# Can you use CRTP and functions taking an interface as a parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

In C++ pure virtual classes are often used for runtime polymorphism.

So you have:

```
class IInterfaceA
{
    virtual void DoFoo() = 0;
};
```

And derived classes like:

```
class CFancyObject : public IInterfaceA
{
...
```

Which then can be used in functions like:

```
void Foo(IInterfaceA &interface);
```

But this is runtime case, and if the objects are known at compile time, we can do better by using CRTP:

```
template<class T> class IInterfaceA
{
public:
    void DoFoo()
    {    
        static_cast<T*>(this)->CallDerivedFunction();
    }
}

class CFancyObject : public IInterfaceA<CFancyObject>
{
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to use CRTP based derived classes in functions that take IInterface as a parameter?

```
void Foo(IInterfaceA<?> &interface);
```

Comment: Can't you just have a non-templated base interface from which the templated interface inherits?

Comment: @Nick: But it has to call member function of a derived class, which has to be calculated at the compile time. I don't quite see how to describe that in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface is meant to decouple the API of a class from its implementation. By introducing a template parameter you are tightly coupling the implementation to the interface, defeating the whole purpose. [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is meant to solve a different set of problems.

If you make the interface templated, the function that takes it as a parameter must be templated as well. Once you've done that there's no difference between using the interface class and using the implementation class.

```
template<class T>
void Foo(IInterfaceA<T> &interface) { interface.DoFoo(); }
```

is identical to and provides no advantages over

```
template<class T>
void Foo(T &object) { object.DoFoo(); }
```

Comment: The difference in coupling is only run time vs compile time. Templated base class still decouples interface from implementation, It would still take less time to switch to completely new derived class implementation. And all derived classes that are derived from Base are actually pretty much interchangeable. I guess even `template<class T> void Foo(IInterfaceA<T> &interface);` would work, but it's still very clumsy and intellisense hostile, so I wonder if there is a neat way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Coder, the point I was trying to make is that the *user* of the interface needs the full definition of the concrete class in order to fill in the template parameter. At that point there's no benefit to the interface class, you could work with the concrete class directly.

Comment: The benefit I see is the DRY. If 3 or 4 classes have same interface, but different implementations, I could use one function to process them all. At the same time avoiding runtime overhead of pure virtual classes and offering compile time error diagnostics. But with DerivedA, DerivedB, DerivedC all of which are based on CRTPBaseA I just see no way how to use one single sink for all of them.

Comment: @MarkRansom One difference is that the IDE will normally offer code completion hints for the first example. It will not for the second. But, that is it.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do:

```
template<class T> class IInterfaceA 
{
public:
    template<class T2>
    void DoFoo(IInterfaceA<T2> &interface)
    {    
        static_cast<T*>(this)->CallDerivedFunction(interface);
    }
}

class CFancyObject : public IInterfaceA<CFancyObject>
{
    template<class T2>
    CallDerivedFunction(IInterfaceA<T2> &interface) {...}
}
```

?